# How to convert a column with nested StructType to a class instance in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For example, `student` column has a `StructType(("id", "int"), ("name", "string"))`

```
| student     |
| ------------|
| [123,james] |
```

How can I convert one column value to a `Student` class instance using `Dataset<Row>.map()` ? Should I treat the column's value as a string array and parse it to construct the instance?

Answer (score 1):

The nested column value is also a `Row`. So we can get properties' values by name and then construct an instance.

Here's some demo code:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, "james"), (2, "tony")).toDF("id", "name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> val dd = df.select(struct("*").alias("students"))
dd: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [students: struct<id: int, name: string>]

scala> dd.show()
+--------------------+
|            students|
+--------------------+
|     [1,james]      |
|     [2,tony]       |
+--------------------+

scala> rows(0).getStruct(0)
res9: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1,james]
```

As we can see, the cell value returned by `rows(0).getStruct(0)` is a `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Encoders and then collect.

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, "james"), (2, "tony")).toDF("id", "name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> val dd = df.select(struct("*").alias("students"))
dd: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [students: struct<id: int, name: string>]

scala> dd.show()
+--------------------+
|            students|
+--------------------+
|     [1,james]      |
|     [2,tony]       |
+--------------------+

scala> case class Student(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Student

scala> dd.select("students.*").as[Student].collectAsList
res6: java.util.List[Student] = [Student(1,james), Student(2,tony)]
```